# Logitech M510 not working after battery replacement?

Tags: mouse, battery, logitech-mouse

I've had this mouse for well over a year now and have never had a single problem up until now. My laptop notified me saying the mouse was low battery, so I changed the batteries out for 2 fresh Duracells (the mouse takes AA's). Now the mouse won't stay on for more than a second. I've tried swapping for a different set of new batteries and am having the same issue. The red tracking laser will turn on for about a second before turning off and not responding.
What do I do??

Comment: Do you have a multimeter or battery tester on hand to confirm that the batteries are in fact full (1,5V)?

Comment: Also, shut the mouse, reboot the PC and turn them on again.

Comment: @mashuptwice no i don't have anything like that but im very certain these are fresh batteries as they came out of a newly opened package of batteries

Comment: @DrMoishePippik since i made this post, I've tried restarting my laptop, uninstalling and reinstalling the mouse driver, and swapping batteries again and the issue still persists

Comment: Perhaps the mouse failed and totally discharged the batteries in the process.